# rewriterule for a set of URLs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to create a rewrite rule for .htaccess , with which I can redirect sub-pages. the rule should make the following thing:

I have hundreds of page which can be accessed under the following path

http://www.domain.de/firma/stadt/adresse

Now I would like to redirect all these URLs to

http://www.domain.de/firma/stadt

for that i used this rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/firma/stadt/(.+)\.(htm|php|html)$ /firma/stadt/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens :-( Where is the mistake?

In addition, I would also like to exclude individual URLs from this rule ... Can someone help me ?

kind regards

Comment: Do you want 
http://www.domain.de/firma/stadt/file.php to redirect to http://www.domain.de/firma/stadt/file?

Comment: no i want that a set of urls like this http://www.domain.de/firma/stadt/adresse redirect to http://www.domain.de/firma/stadt    but i dont know exactly the file structure

Comment: i looked to the server and there are no directories and files for these urls because the urls are generated by the cms... so i think a rewrite rule is not possible? but i tryed redirectmatch and this worked...

Comment: is it possible to exclude a few urls from the redirectmatch??

Comment: Yes, it's possible, so what do you want to exclude?

Comment: i use the the redirectmatch: RedirectMatch 301 /firma/stadt/ http://www.domain.de/firma/stadt$1    and all the urls with http://www.domain.de/firma/stadt/adresse are redirected to /firma/stadt/ no i want to exclude some urls from this rule (for example http://www.domain.de/firma/stadt/adresse1)

Comment: RedirectMatch directive uses regex  to match parts of a URI , try regex to exclude **address1** =>  **RedirectMatch ^/firma/stdt/((?!address1).*)$ /firma/stdt/$1**

Comment: ok i will try it! when i use regex i have to declare the exact url alias or i a part of the url enough? for example i have an url like this domain.de/firma/stadt/adresse1-something1-something2 is  your expression **RedirectMatch ^/firma/stdt/((?!adresse1).*)$ /firma/stdt/$1** then enough or need i **RedirectMatch ^/firma/stdt/((?!adresse1-something1-something2).*)$ /firma/stdt/$1**

Comment: You need to use a pipe **|** to exclude more parts of a uri, forexample, if you want to exclude **foo** and **bar** ,then your regex would be **((?!foo|bar).*)**

Comment: ok, when i exclude **foo** and **bar**  as in your example the urls for example from this type are excludes from the redirectmatch   **www.domain.de/firma/stadt/foo-to-you** and **www.domain.de/firma/stadt/bar-the-star**

Comment: i tryed this and it doesnt work: **RedirectMatch 301 /citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen/((?!trachtenvogl).*) http://www.city-news.info/citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen$1** i want to exclude this url: http://www.city-news.info/citycards/citycards-locations/muenchen from the redirectMatch...Can you see a mistake?

Comment: Why don't you ask a new question with this issue?  it will help you solve the problem quickly.

Comment: ok, i will ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with the logic of your rewrite rule. Try this instead:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^firma/stadt/(.+)$ /firma/stadt/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Reasons:

1. according to your own description the URLs of the objects to *not* carry a "file name extension" in them `http://www.domain.de/firma/stadt/adresse`. So a rule expecting such will never match.
2. the leading slash (`/`) in the mathcing pattern does not make any sense in `.htaccess` style rules, since those work on relative paths.

Also you have to take care of where to place that `htaccess` style file.

A general note: you should only use `.htaccess` style files if you really, really have to. A typical situation might be if you do not have access the the http servers configuration. Otherwise you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration. `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and *really* slow the server down.